# Delivery Optimization service is hogging all my bandwidth, how to stop it?

Tags: windows-10, internet, services, bandwidth

I installed Windows 10 Home on my laptop. I have noticed that there is a process 'Service Host: Delivery Optimization' is hogging all the bandwidth. I am unable to use my internet for browsing.

From this [link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/b94d8e74-58de-451a-b137-7ec2028adc27/delivery-optimization-service-downloading-something-and-using-all-my-bandwidth?forum=win10itprogeneral) I gather that you can disable it by turning off the setting of 'Updates from more than one place'. I did it and restarted my PC and it still didn't work. I can see this service in `services.msc` and its set to 'Automatic (Delayed Start)'. Shouldn't this service be disabled when I turn off 'Updates from more than one place'?

How can I get this service to not run? Is it safe if I disable this service from 'services.msc'?

Comment: Note that "using all the bandwitdh" is in fact the point of bandwidth optimization. Bandwidth cannot be saved; bandwidth you don't use today won't be available tomorrow. However, the optimization should give priority to interactive use (i.e. browsing & email)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, so there is another setting that needs to be turned off. Excerpt from this [link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking/windows-10-delivery-optimization-hogging-bandwidth/c37c3a1f-fba3-40d8-b8c3-6f4f5c61a511) (this explains quite a few other things also).

> I took me until a few days ago to realize it was not Windows Update
> after all but actually an app (game) that I installed recently from
> Windows Store was updating itself. So I tried these steps:
>
> 1. Open Windows Store app
> 2. Go to Settings (click you profile picture to access the menu)
> 3. Switch off the "Update apps automatically"
>
> It solved my problem for now but this is just a workaround and you will have to update Windows Store apps manually from here on.

You may want to uninstall apps that you may not require because they will require updating but you may never use them.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem with Windows 10 and my Data Dongle. My "Update apps automatically" was already off but still Windows 10 was hogging 12mbps or I would say the max the Data Dongle could offer. What helped me is to Set the connection as Metered Connection. If you also fall into the same problem - Click on "Properties" of the network connection and check the "Set as metered connection button.

[image]

[image]